# How to show only two numbers after decimal using php eval() or round()?

Tags: php

I am calculating result of my expression using `eval()`  function but its showing all the numbers afer decimal and I want to show only two numbers after decimal 
this is my eval function  with other data that I have stored.

```
    $expression = generate_expression($num_operands, 
    $operations, $num_digits);
    $expression_string = implode(" ", $expression);
    $result = eval("return ($expression_string);");
    $expressions[] = compact("expression", "result");
```

I am storing the expression_

for this I tried using round function also but its not showing the result that I want 
here is the round function for the `$result`

```
 <?php echo round($result,2); ?>
```

Where I went wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `printf("%.2f", $result)` ? But if `$result` is a string you may have to cast it to `float`. `%.2f` formats the output to two decimals.

Answer (score 2):

> **Use:** [number_format()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_string_number_format)

```
<?php echo number_format((float)$result, 2); ?>
```

> [Example](https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_string_number_format)